# Given 3 sets of 5 random integers from 1 to 100, what is the probability that the 3 sets are mutually inclusive/overlap?

Tags: probability

So let's say I have 3 sets of 5 random integers from 1 to 100 -

$A =\{1, 2, 3, 4, 9\}$

$B = \{2, 3, 6, 1, 12\}$

$C = \{10, 7, 8, 15, 22\}$

$A \cap B \cap C$ = $\emptyset$

However, if we have something like:

$A =\{1, 2, 3, 4, 9\}$

$B = \{2, 3, 6, 1, 12\}$

$C = \{2, 7, 8, 15, 22\}$

$A \cap B \cap C$ = $\{2\}$

How can I solve this?

---

Furthermore, I would like to generalize this to say we have $n$ sets of $m$ random integers in the range of $t$, where $n$ is the number of sets, $m$ is the size of the set, and $t$ is the total numbers to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have chosen the first set. There are ${100\choose5}^2$ ways to choose the next two sets.  For $k=0,1,\dots,5$, there are ${5\choose k}{95\choose5-k}$ ways to choose a second set that has exactly $k$ elements in common with the first set.  There are then ${100-k\choose 5}$ ways to choose a third set not containing any of these elements.  The probability that the intersection is empty is $$
{\sum_{k=0}^5 {5\choose k}{95\choose5-k}{100-k\choose 5}\over{100\choose5}^2}\approx0.9875407739246874$$   and the probability that they have nonempty intersection is, of course, the complement of this.